# How to delete a node in csproj file in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, csproj

I want to delete the node `<Reference Include="System.Data" />`

from the csproj file programmatically.
My csproj file file structure is like this :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.OracleClient" />
    <Reference Include="System.Messaging" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I'm trying to it with this code but its not working:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fullFilePath);
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/Project/ItemGroup/Reference[@Include='System.Data']");

node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);

doc.Save(fullFilePath);
```

Comment: "It's not working" is *never* enough information. What happens when you try it? (I suspect the problem is that you're ignoring the namespace of the element, which is defaulted by the `xmlns=...` part of the root element. I'd also suggest using LINQ to XML as a generally better API, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: you should use XmlNamespaceManager. jon skeet spotted! he's #1!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy with XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<Root>" +
                    "<ItemGroup>" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"Microsoft.CSharp\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Data.OracleClient\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Messaging\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Web.DynamicData\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Web.Entity\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Web.ApplicationServices\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Data\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Core\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Data.DataSetExtensions\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Web.Extensions\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Xml.Linq\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Drawing\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Web\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Xml\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Configuration\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.Web.Services\" />" +
                        "<Reference Include=\"System.EnterpriseServices\" />" +
                      "</ItemGroup>" +
                  "</Root>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
            List<XElement> itemGroup = doc.Descendants("ItemGroup").ToList();

            itemGroup.Elements("Reference").Where(x => x.Attribute("Include").Value == "System.Data").Remove();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 1):

When you a SelectNodes or SingleSelectNodes returns nothing, it means your query is wrong. In this case, elements in a .csproj belong to a namespace (here declared as the "default" namespace - w/o a prefix)

```
<Project ... xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
</Project>
```

So your code must be changed into this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsmgr.AddNamespace("p", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");
doc.Load(fullFilePath);
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/p:Project/p:ItemGroup/p:Reference[@Include='System.Data']", nsmgr);

node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);

doc.Save(fullFilePath);
```

Note the prefix "p" can be anything, it just allows you to specify a corresponding namespace in the XPATH expression, but you need it, even if in the original document it's declared as the default namespace.